# I have Installed Newtonsoft.Json from manage Nuget packages in Visual studio yet I get The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found

Tags: json.net

I have downloaded a tutorial file in which the tutor is explaing how to use Moralis to connect a wallet to a Unity game. However in many of the scripts it needs to use Newtonesoft.Json which apparently it can't.
I have already installed Newtonsoft.Json using NuGet package manager in Visual studio both in version 2022 and 2019. But yet I get this error.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp D:\work\UNITY\Moralis test2\Moralis test2\Assets\MoralisWeb3ApiSdk\Moralis\Moralis.Web3Api.Core\Models\NftTransfer.cs   6   Active
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHnk7.png)